# Error - Segmentation fault - Invalid permissions

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, simulation, lammps

I am trying to run a simulation of Lammps software in a cluster with Linux environment, however my simulation crashes returning the error below.

```
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Invalid permissions (2)
Failing at address: 0x7fc6e59a7308
[ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x12d80)[0x7fc6e5f7ad80]
[ 1] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_vader.so(+0x4b1b)[0x7fc6d247eb1b]
[ 2] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.40(opal_progress+0x34)[0x7fc6e566c8e4]
[ 3] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40(ompi_request_default_wait+0x12d)[0x7fc6e6d32e4d]
[ 4] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_sendrecv_actual+0xc5)[0x7fc6e6d911c5]
[ 5] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40(ompi_coll_base_allreduce_intra_recursivedoubling+0x2dc)[0x7fc6e6d9159c]
[ 6] /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.40(PMPI_Allreduce+0x2c0)[0x7fc6e6d46fc0]
[ 7] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0xed9299]
[ 8] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x771650]
[ 9] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x44cf50]
[10] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x157f206]
[11] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x157d2f7]
[12] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x157dddb]
[13] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x417496]
[14] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7fc6e5bc7813]
[15] /home/sw/lammps/LAMMPS_7AUG19/lammps-7Aug19-Full_2/src/lmp_g++_openmpi[0x4178fe]
*** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 9 with PID 0 on node lesc exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I believe that this error should not be directly related to the software but rather with mpi.

Could anyone kindly give me any insight into this kind of error? I don't understand much about how mpi works.

Comment: This is either a bug in (this specific version of) Open MPI, or a bug in the (version of the) application that invokes `MPI_Allreduce()` with the wrong parameters. An option is to rebuild LAMMPS with `MPICH` and see how things go: that should give you a good pointer to where you should believe the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @GillesGouaillardet , I appreciated that!